# How to handle double value if it is null?

Tags: null, double

I am adding column `columnX` (double) value to datatable it has the `value=null`, so I am getting the exception, I have tried (double?) but after checking the value I am able to add (double) value to double column. How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if result is **"DbNull" or DBNull** nor sure on capitalisation

ie:

```
if(newRow[field] is DBNull){
//handle for null value
}else{
newRow[field] = value
}
```